# Python Code optimizer for list of list choices conbination

Tags: python, list, recursion, optimization

I have python code to find all the possible choices from the list of lists. But when I have a big size list it gives a larger possible dataset. My function is,

```
def yield_combos(lst):
    if not lst:
        yield []
    else:
        for el in lst[0]:
            for combo in yield_combos(lst[1:]):
                yield [el] + combo
```

Above code to the input of,

```
l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[0,2,7]]
```

output is,

```
[1, 4, 0]
[1, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 5, 0]
[1, 5, 2]
[1, 5, 7]
[1, 6, 0]
[1, 6, 2]
[1, 6, 7]
[2, 4, 0]
[2, 4, 2]
[2, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 0]
[2, 5, 2]
[2, 5, 7]
[2, 6, 0]
[2, 6, 2]
[2, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 0]
[3, 4, 2]
[3, 4, 7]
[3, 5, 0]
[3, 5, 2]
[3, 5, 7]
[3, 6, 0]
[3, 6, 2]
[3, 6, 7]
```

Now I want to reduce the output list with a condition like, all the possible list should include at least one list first item. 
Then it should remove below item from the list,

```
[2,5,2]
[2,5,7]
[2,6,2]
[2,6,7]
[3,5,2]
[3,5,7]
[3,6,2]
[3,6,7]
```

This will help to optimize my algorithm for a large list. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking, how can I trim the final list using a generic conditional?  Or are you asking, how can I remove items from the final list that do not contain any first element?

Comment: Actually I want to ask, how can I trim the final list using a generic conditional? , Its no need to use my code, if you have any other solution, its ok

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the function as such:

```
def yield_combos(lst, includes_head_item=False):
    if not lst:
        if not includes_head_item:
            return
        yield []
    else:
        for el_index, el in enumerate(lst[0]):
            for combo in yield_combos(lst[1:], includes_head_item or el_index == 0):
                yield [el] + combo
```

We use the variable `includes_head_item` to keep track of whether any sublist's head item has been included in the combo. If we reach the end with that condition still false, the code is structured such that we don't `yield`, removing that combination from the generated ones.

If you wanted to make such a function for other indices as well (for example, ensuring that each combination includes atleast one element at the end of a sublist), you could do this:

```
def yield_combos(lst, included_index=0, includes_item=False):
    if not lst:
        if not includes_item:
            return
        yield []
    else:
        for el_index, el in enumerate(lst[0]):
            for combo in yield_combos(lst[1:], included_index, includes_item or el_index == included_index):
                yield [el] + combo
```

To accomplish the above example for including atleast one last element, you would call it as such:

```
yield_combos(..., 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

the combination list can be achieved with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

For example `product('ABCD', 'xy')` gives `Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy`, thus for your example:

```
itertools.product([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[0,2,7])
```

As for the final conditioning on zeros, it is simply excluding `0` from your initial list! (isn't it?!) but you can also do the conditioning with later `if` or `assert` checks